# Clarification on Many to one Association

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have two tables called Stock and stock_daily_record. Please find the table structure below

**Stock**

Id (primary key) Int

Name varchar

**stock_daily_record**

Stockid(primary key & foreign key on id of Stock)

Stock_price (Primary key)

**My Entity class**

```
@Entity  @Table(name = "stock")
class Stock 
{
  @id  @column(name=”id”)
  Private int id;

  @column(name=”name”)
  Private String name;

  @oneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  Private Set<DailyStockRecord> dailyRecords;

  //Getters and setters,equals
 }
```

My next class DailyStockRecord contains composite key alone. How to define mapping between this two classes. Plus how to define DailyStockRecord entity?

**Note:**
       Please don't consider my Database design cos I tried to project my actual problem through this dummy design

Comment: Your database design makes no sense. If a stock can have many records, the stock_id can't be the primary key of the stock_daily_record table: a primary key, by definition, must be unique. Add another column and make it the primary key, and make stock_id a foreign key only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration

```
  @Entity
  @Table("stock_daily_record")
   public class DailyStockRecord

        @EmbeddedId
        private DailyStockId stockId;

        @MapsId("stockId")
        @ManyToOne
        private Stock stock;
```

And the embeddable key as follows:

```
@Embeddedable
public class DailyStockId 

    private int dailyStockId;
    private int stockId;
```

And update your code to

```
@Entity  
@Table(name = "stock")
public class Stock 

  @id  @column(name=”id”)
  Private int id;

  @column(name=”name”)
  Private String name;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="stock" )
  Private Set<DailyStockRecord> dailyRecords;

  //Getters and setters,equals
 }
```

Comment: Got the below error when tried this mapping _Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property:_

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity  @Table(name = "stock_daily_record")
class StockDailyRecord 
{
  @id  @column(name=”Stockid”)
  Private int stockId;

  @column(name=”Stock_price”)
  Private String stockPrice;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @joinColumn(name="id")
  Private Stock stock;

  //Getters and setters,equals
 }
```

Comment: This suggestion too gave me the below error _Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property:_

Comment: can you provide full  stack trace of this exception